# Mysql cli and phpmyadmin - Give different results

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have the following query:

```
SELECT `report_table_cottage_rented`.`cottage_id`     AS 
       report_table_cottage_rented___SP___cottage_id, 
       `report_table_cottage_rented`.`cottage_name`   AS 
       report_table_cottage_rented___SP___cottage_name, 
       `report_table_cottage_rented`.`end_time`       AS 
       report_table_cottage_rented___SP___end_time, 
       `report_table_cottage_rented`.`rented_days`    AS 
       report_table_cottage_rented___SP___rented_days, 
       `report_table_cottage_rented`.`rented_weekend` AS 
       report_table_cottage_rented___SP___rented_weekend, 
       `report_table_cottage_rented`.`rented_weeks`   AS 
       report_table_cottage_rented___SP___rented_weeks, 
       `report_table_cottage_rented`.`start_time`     AS 
       report_table_cottage_rented___SP___start_time 
FROM   `report_table_cottage_rented` 
WHERE  1 && ( `report_table_cottage_rented`.`start_time` BETWEEN 
                          '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31 23:59:59' )
```

and it seems just fine to me.

The query above gives different results when run through mysql cli (only 2 results - wrong) than through phpmyadmin (5410 results - right).

I get the same wrong answer when the query runs through the php build-in function mysql_query().

I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: Why ` 1 && ` is needed in where statememt?

Comment: No I don't think so, but it doesn't make any difference, I thought it did as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your `between` must be : `BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-31 23:59:59'` . Else mysql will use the actuall timestamp which leeds to different results over the time.

BTW: Do not use deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: Yes indeed it's deprecated, but this query is from a really old system that hasn't been updated yet, that's why it uses old functions.

Comment: I've tried PDO as well, it did give me the same result.

Comment: I did try changing it to: `BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-31 23:59:59'` I got the same result, it didn't work. ;(

Comment: @None You mean differnet results between cli and phpmyadmin?

Comment: Yes, exactly, mysql cli 2 results, phpmyadmin 5410 results.

Comment: You are sure you use the same DB for both (cli and phpmyadmin)?

Comment: Yes, it just did try to explicitly specifying the database from the query: http://pastebin.com/HWU27eE6 still got the same result. ;(